# Qt: Shared C Library Exported From Golang

Tags: c++, qt, go, shared-libraries

I was doing some tests with Golang exporting shared libraries that can be used in C and came up with the following:

calcLib.go:

```
package main
import "C"

//export Calculator
func Calculator(x int, y int) int {
    return x+y;
}

func main() {
    // Need a main function to make CGO compile package as C shared library
}
```

This simple library contains the `Calculator` that sums numbers. Now I've a small C program that will use it:

calc.c:

```
#include "calcLib.h"

int main() {     
    printf("Hello World from C!\n");     
    printf("Calculator() -> %d\n", Calculator(10,5));
    return 0;
}
```

Now I can compile the library and the C program with:

```
C:\Users\TCB13\Desktop
> go build -buildmode c-shared -o calcLib.a calcLib.go
C:\Users\TCB13\Desktop
> gcc -o calc.exe calc.c calcLib.a
```

This will output an executable that works as expected:

```
> .\calc.exe
Hello World from C!
Calculator() -> 15
```

**Now, how can I use this shared library in a Qt project?**

I tried to add the following to my .pro file:

```
LIBS += -L"C:\Users\TCB13\shared\calcLib.a"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Users\TCB13\shared"  # Shared folder includes the calcLib.h file
```

Then in my main.cpp:

```
#include "testapp.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QtDebug>
#include "calcLib.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    TestApp w;
    w.show();

    qDebug() << Calculator(10,5);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Compiling this results in the following errors:

[image]

**How can I properly make/export/use this library in a Qt Application?**

Here is my calcLib.h file for reference: https://pastebin.com/k3sKYiti

Thank you.

Comment: LIBS += -LC:/Users/TCB13/shared -lcalcLib

Comment: @mugiseyebrows your solution worked with a tweak. I had to change the library name to `libCalc`. Then added `LIBS += -L$${PWD}\shared -lCalc` and `INCLUDEPATH += $${PWD}\shared` and it worked. Apparently there are some naming conventions in Qt. Also moved the lib to the `project-folder/shared`. If you answer that solution I'll accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In qmake project files `LIBS` variable uses same cli keys as gcc linker `-L` to specify searchpath for libraries and `-l` for library name (without `lib` prefix and without `.a` or `.dll` or `.so` suffix, I believe version with prefix should also work).

So it should be `LIBS += -L$${PWD}\shared -lCalc`

[qmake-variable-reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs)